# How to run Spring Boot and Keycloak on local network

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, firewall, windows-firewall

I have a micro-service based project using Keycloak, Spring Boot apps and others...
The project works perfectly on localhost. And now I want to test it on other devices like my phone on the same local network.

I know my PC's IP Address (it's reserved on the router so it does not change).

But somehow I can't access it.

1. First I tried testing the connection to Keycloak Admin Console ***And it Failed***
2. I Checked the Keycloak configuartion to check if the app is exposed to outer traffic ***And it did***
3. I was certain that the problem was with my firewall so I disabled it ***It worked***
4. I tried to create some custom rule to allow the process traffic ***I couldn't find the keycloak Program***
5. I tried to create custom rule to expose the ports to any program or process to any incoming connection in the network IP pool ***It didn't work***
6. I tried to create custom rule to allow the IP address of the my phone to access any PORT app or process ***Still didn't work***

What can I do? I don't want to disable my firewall

> The PC Hosting the backend uses Windows Defender Firewall. (No Judging, it's for testing before prod)

I'm running Keycloak with

```
kc.bat start-dev
```

Spring Boot apps are packaged as JAR

```
java -jar PATH_TO_JAR/jarname.jar com.example.package.ClassName -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Answer (score 1):

try it on your local machine by its IP address, if it's not with the keycloak. if it's working try to disable your antivirus. if you can post the error also  with deployment information.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to set the `hostname` in Keycloak configuration to something valid for all your devices. This property is used to set the issuer claim and you could have token validation problems if issuer is left to `localhost` (other devices won't fetch JWK-set from localhost...).

Here is the complete conf I use to run Keycloak in "production" mode on my dev machine:

```
db=postgres
db-username=keycloak
db-password=change-me
db-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/keycloak

# Hostname of my MSI Bravo on the local network
hostname=bravo-ch4mp

http-enabled=true
http-port=8442
https-key-store-file=change-me.jks
https-key-store-password=change-me
https-port=8443
```

In addition to installing [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) and [generating self-signed certificates](https://github.com/ch4mpy/self-signed-certificate-generation), I also configured a small DNS server for local networks where my machine is not resolvable by name (some routers include a DNS, some don't...). Details for MaraDNS configuration in my repo for certificates generation.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I found out that there was a rule in the fire wall preventing the java.exe of the JDK-19 from accessing the device's ports.

Ironically, only Keycloak was using the JDK-19 while the rest used older versions. So the problem was only with keycloak.

Even though I made a rule to allow keycloak, the fact that in its code it's calling java.exe made the rule ineffective because the blocking rules have priority over the allowing rules.